# Confusion about Matrix Multiplication as Function Composition

Tags: linear-algebra

I've got some confusion about matrix multiplication as function composition. This has to do with a discrepancy between the size of the multiplied matrix, and the kind of linear function it's supposed to represent.

If we have two functions, $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$, and $g:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$. Their composition is such that, $f\circ g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$.

$f$ is represented by a $3\times2$ matrix, and $g$ is represented by a $2\times3$ matrix. (The number of rows reflects the dimension of the output set of the function, while the columns reflects the dimension of the input set.)

The discrepancy is as follows. On the one hand, we would expect $f\circ g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ to be represented by a $2\times 2$ matrix. On the other hand, the computational rule of matrix multiplication $f\times g$ is such that we will get a $3\times 3$ matrix (as a $3\times 2$ matrix is multiplied by a $2\times 3$ matrix.)

Comment: $f \circ g $ does map $R^3$ to $R^3$, check again.

Comment: Maybe there is some confusion about $f \circ g$ vs $g \circ f$. In standard notation, $f \circ g$ means "do g first, then do f to the result of g".

Comment: Oh yes, that is indeed a confusion on function composition on my part! Thank you!

Comment: It's defined that way so the order is consistent with $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$. Unfortunately it's not consistent with the way we write the arrows $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^3$; it would be clearer if we wrote $f:\mathbb R^3\leftarrow\mathbb R^2$ and $g:\mathbb R^2\leftarrow\mathbb R^3$, but we don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your confusion.  If $f: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3} \text{, and } g:\mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2} \text{, then the composition is}$ $f \circ g: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$, not $f \circ g: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2} \text{ as you mentioned.}$  This is because $f \circ g$ means apply $g$ first and then apply $f$.  Your matrix dimensions are correct and the rest of your reasoning is good.